# Laravel 4 - Declare class globally?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the package "Steam Condenser" in my Laravel 4 project.  Once the user logs in to my application, I set a session with their ID (steamId).  This ID can be used to grab various data (Name, Avatar etc), an example:

```
$steamUser = new SteamId( Session::get('steamId') );
$username = $steamUser->getNickname();
```

Now this works, however I'm going to be using this data on a lot of the pages (and also in the controllers).  What I don't want to be doing is declaring a new class everytime - so my question is:

- Can create the SteamId, so in my controllers I only need to say `$username = $steamUser->getNickname();` - obviously only if `(Session::has('steamId'))` is true.

I see two ways of doing this:

1. Via a __constructor, however I cannot get this to work (failing horribly).
2. Via a route filter.  So making a new filter name and for every route doing a `'before' => 'filter'`.  However this could become quite over excessive.

I hope this makes sense (my PHP knowledge isn't so great) - basically I don't want to do `new SteamId( Session::get('steamId') );` all the time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the IoC container, as mentioned by Dave Ganley. It allows you to define how an object is called/handled, and you simply resolve that class when the time comes, eg:

```
App::singleton('SteamId', function($app)
{
    return new SteamId(Session::get('steamId'));
});
```

Then when you need it, resolve it:

```
$steamIdObject = App::make('SteamId');
```

Will give you all methods for that class. And because it will act like a singleton - it will only ever be instantiated once.

In addition, you could tie this in with route filters and groups to ensure that this always gets called on every page, and sets the data you require. Then in your controllers, just call the same object via App::make and you're good to go :)

Comment: Thanks this worked - one thing though, since my app will depend heavily on using $steamIdObject, is it possible to load it within BaseController, so I can use the variable within every other Controller? If so, what's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You absolutely could. I would still use the IoC, but also add it to the constructor of your base controller or something, as mentioned in the answer below :)

So, just do:

    $this->steamIdObject = App::make('SteamId');

Then in your controllers, just refer to $this->steamIdObject :)

Comment: Btw, a benefit of using this approach means that your controllers are more testable. Always use the IoC for objects if you can - and if you can't, use Facades :)

Comment: Thanks very much! Explained nicely :)

Comment: Is is possible to modify the value of the singleton?

Comment: Why would you want to @jplozano? Singleton isn't meant to be changed. You could use other types of IoC bindings if you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor would be the most straightforward. If you tend to run the same code over and over in a class, then that's what the constructor is helpful for.

```
class WhateverController extends BaseController
{
  private $steamUser;
  private $data = array();

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->steamUser = new SteamId(...);
    $data['steamUser'] = $this->steamUser;

    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function doSomething()
  {
    $nickname = $this->steamUser->getNickname();
    $something = Whatever:all();

    $this->data['something'] = $something;

    return View::make('myview', $this->data);

  }
}
```

You could always extend a custom base class controller as well.

Comment: That'll only do it for the controllers though, not for views and other files.

Comment: I plan on sending the data via the controller.  However, I get the error Undefined property: SteamController::$steamUser.  Here's my cut down code if it helps: http://paste.laravel.com/xxN Hopefully you see what I'm trying to do!

Comment: For views you would either need to pass the value to the view, or get the value in a View Composer. I've updated my code to show how you can easily and automatically pass the `steamUser` to the view. Just as long as you pass `$this->data` to the view, it will be accessible in the view.

Comment: Try moving `parent::__construct()` outside that if statement. It should be the last thing to runs at the end of the constructor. I'm not sure what the rest of the problem is though, just looking at it...

Comment: Since $steamUser is in my BaseController, I made it public (and it did something (not sure if that's correct though)), however I now get "Call to a member function getNickname() on a non-object".  Also removed the if statement for now.  I can't seem to create the construct in the SteamController, since it says I cannot redeclare __construct again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the IOC container http://four.laravel.com/docs/ioc

Comment: Upped your response as my response extends yours with extra details.